# git shorthand for fetch && reset --mixed?

Tags: git

`git pull` - a shorthand for `git fetch && git merge`

I've got a live server where I want to stick a repo so I can compare differences between the server files and the repo, but I don't want a pull to start changing files.

The way to do this is with something like `git fetch origin master && git reset --mixed origin/master`

Is there a shorthand for this similar to `git pull`? Perhaps a `git pull --no-worktree` flag or something?

I haven't been able to find anything myself, so I presume I'll need an alias. What's the easiest way to get two git commands in a single alias that works on really old versions of git? (at least 1.7.0)

Comment: I think you should explain a bit more what you're actually doing/aiming for (a bit more context). Otherwise with the plethora of git commands and switches, there is a lot room to guess. For the alias: git-somescript executable normally does it very well and it's more or less bash and not git alias itself. write in there whatever you want. have that script in your path. call `git somescript` ftw.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually avoid to check out another branch for comparing things at all. You can compare your local branch and the remote one using

```
git fetch origin master
git diff HEAD origin/master
```

This way you can avoid a dirty state in the repository on your live server and still view the differences. If you are committing changes on your live server too, you could also use `git diff HEAD...origin/master`, which only shows you the changes done in the remote branch and not yet available in your local branch.

Comment: Well the dirty state comes from lax development practices and people FTPing whatever they like to the server, so it will be dirty either way :)

Comment: In that case it seems even more important to not mix up changes done via ftp and those occuring due to the pull.

Comment: That's why I want `fetch && reset`, not `fetch && merge`

Comment: `fetch && reset` will leave you with a mix of the previously uncommitted changes and the opposite of the changes which would be done by the `pull`. Reading your question I thought that you just wanted to compare the server version and the version from the remote repository. To do that there is not need to change the state of your local repository. If there is any reason to do that, you should clarify your question.